Cleveref \crefname for both full and abbreviated automatically
I have an equation environment that features essentially a family of equations in one line, thus, naturally, I would like to reference it as Equations~(1) or Eqs.~(1) rather than Equation~(1) or Eq.~(1).
One natural solution is to add \label[equations]{eq:smth} and set additional \crefname in the preamble (as in this answer):
\crefalias{equations}{equation}
\crefname{equations}{equations}{equations}
\creflabelformat{equations}{#2\textup{(#1)}#3} % same as 'equation'

However, I would like to future-proof myself and set both the full and abbreviated versions to be controlled by the noabbrev parameter for the cleveref loading and the rules pertaining the beginning of the sentence. Somehow, I do not see immediately how to do this — any advice?

Can you provide a minimal working example? Code snippets are not useful for either reproduction or testing and it isn't at all obvious how your document is marked up (at least to me). Unfortunately, I'm also not sure 'future-proof' and cleveref are compatible.
